# What is preferred implementation of Chrome extension that catches and reads newly added list values on one specific web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I need to create a Chrome extension that will work only for one webpage with specific URL. It will monitor changes to list of items (orders) located on page and if new order appears, it will read some values from order and do something with them. It also may be neccessary to refresh the page from time to time (using timer, maybe).
What architechture will be suitable to accomplish such a task? 
Now - to thoughts I have so far. I think now of using only one content script bound to page URL. Will it be enough? Or should I introduce some background script also? Or anything else?

Comment: A content script sounds sufficient and rather trivial, there's definitely nothing that *needs* a background script although it can be used for some related tasks. The question isn't really answerable.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks. Is it possible to refresh the page in the content script?

Comment: Of course, content scripts are just like normal page scripts so they can use the standard DOM methods e.g. location.reload(). You can see more info in the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm, If you think that's it, please post it as an answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: I don't see the point, I just rephrased the first paragraph from the official documentation on content scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As @wOxxOm said in the comments, creating one content script must be sufficient for reading the values and page refreshing.